# Passing an object in C# that inherits from a generic causes a cast exception with IDispatch

Tags: c#, .net, exception, com, marshalling

I have a COM call I would like to make

```
[DispId(163)]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = 
  MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
object CreatePropertyManagerPage
  ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr), In] string Title,
   [In] int Options,
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch), In] object Handler,
   [In, Out] ref int Errors);
```

The **Handler** property is the one causing me problems. If I pass in an object that inherits from

```
public abstract class PmpBase<TMacroFeature,TData> : IPropertyManagerPage2Handler9
```

then I get a InvalidCastException. However if I remove the generics and pass a class that inherits from

```
public abstract class PmpBase : IPropertyManagerPage2Handler9
```

by hard coding the types in the file then the object passes into the call. I can replicate the same findings by doing

```
new DispatchWrapper(foo)
```

where **foo** is an instance of the class that derives from either the generic ( it fails ) and the non generic ( it passes )version.

I have zero knowledge of COM and am just trying to use the automation interface to solidworks. Am I trying to do something impossible. I haven't found any obvious articles that associate generics with errors with COM.

Comment: Pretty unclear how you went from an abstract class declaration to a concrete object that you passed as the *Handler* argument.  COM does not support generics.

Comment: I said the instance I pass in is from a concrete class that inherits from the  abstract class. When you say COM does not support generics do you mean that any class that inherits from a concrete type is unsupported or declaring a com interface as generic is unsupported.

Comment: The handler argument is actually looking for the interface IPropertyManagerPage2Handler9 which is implemented.  I could probably just make a wrapping proxy that does not involve generic and that might get through the problems. Will try that tomorrow.

Comment: The proxy technique works. I added it as the answer. I still don't understand why it makes a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the problem occurs but the solution is quite easy. I created a proxy class for the interface I was trying to pass to COM.

```
public class PropertyManagerPage2Handler9Wrapper : IPropertyManagerPage2Handler9
{
    readonly IPropertyManagerPage2Handler9 _Implementation;

    public PropertyManagerPage2Handler9Wrapper(IPropertyManagerPage2Handler9 implementation)
    {
        _Implementation = implementation;
    }

    public void AfterActivation()
    {
        _Implementation.AfterActivation();
    }

    public void OnClose(int Reason)
    {
        _Implementation.OnClose(Reason);
    }

    public void AfterClose()
    {
        _Implementation.AfterClose();
    }

    <snip>
}
```

and passed the wrapper to the COM function instead of the original instance. Then there was no class cast exception.

```
var propertyManagerPage = SwApp.CreatePropertyManagerPage
     (_Name, options, new PropertyManagerPage2Handler9Wrapper(this), ref errors);
```

instead of this

```
var propertyManagerPage = SwApp.CreatePropertyManagerPage
    (_Name, options, this, ref errors);
```